# PHP usort DOMNodes by depth

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort php DOMDocument elements by their nodePath so that they end up deepest nested first, then in order they exist in the document within the same parent.

For example, in the following HTML the order attribute is the order in 
which I want the elements to be sorted.

```
<div order='5'>
   <div order='3'>
      <div order='1'></div>
      <div order='2'></div>
   </div>
   <div order='4'></div>
</div>
```

I get tantalizingly close, but not all the way there.

```
//THIS gives me order 2,1,4,3,5 which is deepest nested but not linear
 within the same parent

function dorder($a,$b){
    $bp=count(explode("/",$b->getNodePath()) );
    $ap=count( explode("/",$a->getNodePath()) );
        if($ap==$bp){
            return 0;
        }  
        else if($ap<$bp){
            return 1;
          }

         else{
            return -1;
         }  
  }
```

Sometimes a sort will get some elements in the right order within one parent,
but wrong within another parent...

```
//THIS gives me 1,2,4,3,5 which is right except for 4 and 3 are swapped.
function dorder($a,$b){

$bp=count(explode("/",$b->getNodePath()) );
$ap=count( explode("/",$a->getNodePath()) );
        if($ap==$bp){
            return 1;
        }  
        else if($ap<$bp){
            return 1;
         }

         else{
            return -1;
         }
}
```

**NOTE**
In the actual XML there is no 'order' attribute to work from. It is here only for testing purposes.

Comment: you should need some way of either designating or enforcing elements. There should be a more discrete method in DOMParser which at least should return elements in order of the document. Investigating . . .

Comment: I think there is optimization screwing with me, because similar test results vary. I may have to loop through myself without usort.

Comment: nearly there. Got pulled away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eggmatters convinced me to give up on usort for this and to piggy back off the natural order of returned nodes. I changed the function so I don't add a 'visited' property to each node and I can use it to compare any two or more nodes from a document without having to sort the whole document.

```
function depthSort($nodesArr){
    $sorted=array();
    foreach($nodesArr as $node){
       $i=0;
         $adepth=count(explode("/",$node->getNodePath() ) );
         while($i<count($sorted)){
           $bdepth=count(explode("/",$sorted[$i]->getNodePath()));
           if($adepth>$bdepth){
            array_splice($sorted,$i,0,array($node));
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }   
    //order must go on the end cause it didn't go anywhere else
    if($i==count($sorted)){
        array_push($sorted, $node); 
     }                                               

}
return $sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a way you could go. Instead of usort, you could just depth first the dom stack. You will reliably hit the elements in order:

```
$dom = <<<DOM
<div order='5'>
  <div order='3'>
    <div order='1'></div>
    <div order='2'></div>
  </div>
  <div order='4'></div>
</div>
DOM;

echo "<pre>" . htmlentities($dom) . "</pre>";

$domDocument = new DOMDocument;
$domDocument->loadXML($dom);
$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$domNodes = $domXPath->query('//div');
$nodesArray = array();
orderNodes($domNodes, $nodesArray);

foreach ($nodesArray as $n) {
  echo "order: $n<br>";
}

function orderNodes($domNodes, &$nodesArray) {
  foreach ($domNodes as $divDOM) {
    if ($divDOM->hasChildNodes()) {
      orderNodes($divDOM->childNodes, $nodesArray);
    } 
    if ($divDOM instanceof DOMElement && ! isset($divDOM->visited)) {
      $nodesArray[] = $divDOM->getAttribute('order');
      $divDOM->visited = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Wrestle with the DOMNodes using recursion, depth first. I stuffed a hack in there, setting an arbitrary property: `$divDOM->visited = true;`. This acts somewhat like a filter, preventing duplicate elements from being written as the recursion backs out.

Comment: doing something similar-gave up on usort and walking the array myself.

Comment: yah, let us know what you come up with.